# How to sort array of objects in 3 parts in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, ecmascript-5

I need to sort array of objects in the following way:

1st ones should be objects where favorites array includes only one item
2nd should be shown objects where favorites array is undefined or empty
3rd favorites array has more than 1 items

Total array of objects looks like this:

```
[
{
rentalName:
rentalAdress:
favorites:[]
...
}
]
```

I found a similar solution here but this sorting will not work for the above case:

```
function sortBy(selector) {
  const cmp = (a, b) => (selector(a) - selector(b));
  return list => list.sort(cmp);
}

const data = [{ rentalName: "Foo", favorites:[{}, {}, {}] }, { rentalName: "Bar", favorites:[{}] }, { rentalName: "Baz", favoriteslikes:[{}] }, { Name: "Plugh", favorites:[] }];

const sortByLikes = sortBy(({ favorites }) => favorites.length);

console.log(sortByLikes(data));
```

How to sort array of objects in 3 parts as it was explained above?

Comment: Sorting means putting an array in a particular order. I think you're actually asking about filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't sorting, it's making different groups of elements.

Use a `forEach` loop and push the object onto a different array depending on the condition.

```
function groupByFavorites(array) {
    let result = {
        none: [],
        one: [],
        multiple: []
    };
    array.forEach(o => {
        if (!o.favorites) { // undefined or empty
            result.none.push(o);
        } else if (o.favorites.length == 1) {
            result.one.push(o);
        } else {
            result.multiple.push(o);
        }
        return result;
    });
}
```

Comment: It's not working shows error on return line seems kind of syntax error but not sure why.

Comment: I think I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a number to each case, with the cases that should come first having lower numbers and then subtract the two when comparing.

```js
function sortBy() {
  const getOrder = ({favorites})=>favorites?.length === 1 ? 0 : !favorites?.length ? 1 : 2;
  const cmp = (a, b) => (getOrder(a) - getOrder(b));
  return list => list.sort(cmp);
}

const data = [{ rentalName: "Foo", favorites:[{}, {}, {}] }, { rentalName: "Bar", favorites:[{}] }, { rentalName: "Baz", favoriteslikes:[{}] }, { Name: "Plugh", favorites:[] }];

const sortByLikes = sortBy();

console.log(sortByLikes(data));
```